# blog comments on facebook and on website's page on facebook

Tags: php, html, facebook, facebook-comments

I'm writing a blog in php.
I want facebook comments on every single blog entry. I also want those comments to appear on the website's page on facebook so people from the website and people on facebook which visited the website's page can comment on the same blog entry but from different places.

Here is what I want: When someone comments on a blog entry, the comment should appear on the website's page on facebook with, lets say the title of the blog entry and its picture. After that it should make no difference if you comment on the website or its page.

I have this in my code:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://devbat.com/index.php?page=blog_view&amp;id=<?php echo $id; ?>" data-num-posts="2" data-width="690" data-colorscheme="dark"></div>
```

So facebook knows when there are different entries. The problem is, when I comment, the comment itself goes to my wall in facebook and not in the website's page on facebook.

I also have this script, as instructed on the facebook developers page:

```
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=193822290683618";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

I have seen websites that cross-post their comments on blog entries but I dont know how. Can someone PLEASE give me some help on the subject..

I know there are other questions here on StackOverflow but none of them seem to match my exact situation or the instructions given seem outdated or misleading.

Comment: It sounds like it's doing exactly what it's designed to do. I'm not aware of the API enabling the comment to be posted to the website's page

Comment: There has to be some way to cross post and synchronize both..

Comment: You could be right. I find the Facebook API to be confusing. But, as far as I know, straight out to the box, the commenting feature is doing exactly what it is supposed to do.

Comment: Yes, I know its working. And the API IS confusing. I was hoping that someone over here might have figured something out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are now plug-in libraries/services, such as Disqus that take care of that.

Answer (score 0):

The comments plugin is a very limited, but highly useful, widget.  It will not do what you want it to do.  Your best bet is to create your own "comments" application and datastore that will work both from your blog as well as from a Facebook.  This is doable, as I've done a similar thing (not exact) with the Facebook API.